# Permission denied for genesis.json file

Tags: permissions, chmod

I am having an issue with the persmission of the genesis.json file. I tried to fix it with chmod, but it sadly didnt help. Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

[image]
Also same issue for my config.toml:
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

I am following a tutorial from this site btw: https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html

Comment: Please include console input and output as text, not as images. An image makes it impossible to copy and paste from it and is also often difficult to read.

Comment: Please stop using root. and stop using sudo when using root.

Comment: I understand that i should use sudo with root, because its double. But why shouldnt i use root?

Answer (score 0):

According to the command line documentation for `geth` at https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options, the `--datadir` option to `geth` accepts a single argument which specifies the data *directory* for the databases and keystore. So your command line asks `geth` to use the data directory `node` which probably doesn't exist.

By the way, your screenshots show that you are working as `root`.
You shouldn't. And if you do, you don't need `sudo` on top of it.